# How to avoid sending auth-token cookie to CDN-hosted site?

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I'd like to avoid sending my authentication-token cookie to CDN-hosted site.

The static contents of the site (www.example.com) are served by the CDN. The site makes ajax calls to api.example.com -- all ajax requests to the api.example.com must receive the authtoken cookie.

**What works:**
If api.example.com sets the auth-cookie to ".example.com" domain, ajax requests work, but the cookie is also send to CDN-hosted resources (www.example.com), which is undesired.

**What doesn't work:** If api.example.com sets the auth-cookie to ".api.example.com" domain, subsequent ajax requests are missing the cookie, presumably because of Same-Origin-Policy?

So, is it possible to avoid sending the auth-cookie with every request to www.example.com, and only to api.example.com?

Comment: This is exactly what I tried early on and it just failed flat out. The browsers seem to ignore such Set-Cookie since "api.example.com" does not match the "Origin": www.pushcoin.com.